# How to retrieve a list of public Google Docs from one user

Tags: php, xml, json, google-docs-api

Is there a way to retrieve a JSON or XML resource from Google Docs using an HTTP GET? I want to list public-only docs belonging to me on a web page, so the user viewing the web page should not need authentication or even to have a Google account.

I can do this easily in the Blogger API.

https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/blogId/posts

Don't really care the method (writing in PHP) for retrieving the data, but I want it to happen server side and it should not require authentication by the user.

Have I missed something?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Google Documents List API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/). I believe it only requires auth for non-public data retrieval.

Comment: What did you determine? Why did you pass on it? Does it require OAuth for everything? You could always use a scraper, but you run the risk of getting a C&D letter, as Google will most likely want people to use their API and go through the proper channels.

Comment: I'll pass it on as soon as I figure it out. I've been side tracked by another job but I'll be back to this shortly. Looks like OAuth is necessary even for public and published docs.